# Apply case sensitiveness to the entire scope when validating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 6 app, I have the following validation

```
class Cake < ApplicationRecord
end

class Holiday < ApplicationRecord
  validates :cake, uniqueness: { scope: [:year, :code] }
end
```

Is there a way to add `case_sensitive` to the validation so with the following record in my DB

```
 |cake_id|year|code|
 |1 |2001|xyz |
```

The following model is not valid

```
Holiday.new(cake_id: 1, year: 2001, code: 'xYz')
```

I have tried with

```
 validates :cake, uniqueness: { scope: [:year, :code],
                                case_sensitive: false }
```

But it seems to apply only to `cake`.

**UPDATE**

One way to achieve what I need is to move the `uniqueness` validation to the `code`. In this way, the `case_sensitive` applies to the only attribute of the 3 which needs to be checked for case sensitiveness (year is an integer and case an ActiveRecord).

```
  class Holiday < ApplicationRecord
      validates :code, uniqueness: { scope: [:year, :cake],
                                     case_sensitive: false }
  end
```

Comment: You said "Both of the following" and I only see one.

Comment: It was a typo, fixed

Comment: can you include the SQL produced when you run `h = Holiday.new(cake_id: 1, year: 2001, code: 'xYz'); h.valid?` in rails console ?

Comment: I solved the issue by moving the uniqueness validation to the `code`. Thanks.

Comment: could you please add your complete code to answer so that I could learn?

Comment: See the update for my solution.

Comment: Now I see your solution and I remembered that once we had the same scenario and we achieved what we want by validating `cake_id` instead of `cake`.